# Handling Teams with permissions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I wonder what the best practice is to handle teams with different sets of active records, through the whole database.

Lets say we have a app which is used by different teams. Every team can access all the active records belonging to them but not the active records belonging to a other team.

The primitive way would be

1. add a team_id to every record
2. in every create add the team_id of current user to active record
3. to every query add where(team_id = current_user.team_id)
4. use pundit or equal gem for permissions

I wonder if theres a better way. For example, in the model add the team_id with after_initialization.
Is it possible to automatically add team_id = current_user.team_id to every query? What would be the best way to handle that? Is there a gem?

Comment: there's a nifty little trick described in this blog, maybe this helps? - http://geekhmer.github.io/blog/2016/01/27/how-to-make-session-data-available-to-models-in-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: You can checkout the [apartment gem](https://github.com/influitive/apartment). It creates different schemas for each "tenant" (or, in your case, team). Heres a good [writeup](https://medium.com/@tiagoandrgeraldi/rails-app-with-multi-tenancy-without-subdomains-25941fe876ec) explaining how to use it without subdomains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Every team can access all the active records belonging to them", that is your answer, in my opinion. All record should belongs to a team. Pundit is designed to build policies about actions (with or without roles), you need the team id to know from where the records comes so Pundit is not your best option. This is what I would do

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :notes
end

class Note < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
end
```

After login you will have the current_user so you have the team too

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def current_user
    return unless session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

  def current_team
    return unless current_user
    @current_team ||= current_user.team
  end  
end
```

then you can chain associations (or use delegates) to get your records

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @notes = current_user.team.notes
  end
end
```

or

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @notes = current_team.notes
  end
end
```

I hope it helps.